# Creating stacked barplots in R using different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am a novice R user, hence the question. I refer to the solution on creating stacked barplots from [R programming: creating a stacked bar graph, with variable colors for each stacked bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619069/r-programming-creating-a-stacked-bar-graph-with-variable-colors-for-each-stack).

My issue is slightly different. I have 4 column data. The last column is the summed total of the first 3 column. I want to plot bar charts with the following information 1) the summed total value (ie 4th column), 2) each bar is split by the relative contributions of each of the three column.

I was hoping someone could help.

Regards,
Bernard

Comment: How's that different from the question you linked? When you plot stacked bars, the total height is already the sum by groups, and the colors are divided proportionally.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it rightly, this may do the trick

the following code works well for the example df dataframe

```
df <-  a   b    c   sum
       1    9   8   18
       3    6   2   11
       1    5   4   10
      23    4   5   32
       5    12  3   20
       2    24  1   27
       1    2   4   7
```

As you don't want to plot a counter of variables, but the actual value in your dataframe, you need to use the goem_bar(stat="identity") method on ggplot2. Some data manipulation is necessary too. And you don't need a sum column, ggplot does the sum for you.

```
df <- df[,-ncol(df)]            #drop the last column (assumed to be the sum one)
df$event <- seq.int(nrow(df))   #create a column to indicate which values happaned on the same column for each variable
df <- melt(df, id='event')      #reshape dataframe to make it readable to gpglot

px = ggplot(df, aes(x = event, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
print (px)
```

this code generates the plot bellow

[image]

Comment: the method worked very well. A perculiar thing is happening when stacking. My base units of the y-variable is very small to two decimal places (range 0.1-0.01). When I plot, the scale of y varies from 0-40. Almost as if, every observation is scaled. Attached is a sample of my script "Figure3<-ggplot(Run_dataset_Neg1,aes(x=as.factor(Load),y=Neg_work_mag,fill=as.factor(Joint)))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray78","gray31","black"),labels=c("Ankle","Hip","Knee"))"